# PHP can't connect to Xdebug client on Docker

Tags: php, docker, xdebug, wsl-2

I am using WSL2 with installed docker-ce with PHP 8 and Xdebug 3. After a lot of debugging I figured out that simply PHP can't connect to Xdebug client for whatever reasons. It works when I am using telnet. Logs are empty, not information at all why connection does not work.

I downloaded dbgpClient to make sure it's not IDE issue (PhpStorm) from Xdebug page. `./dbgpClient -1` started it like this. When I do `telnet host.docker.internal 9003` inside the container i have:

```
Connect from 172.20.0.5:45144
```

However if I try running for example `php8 -dxdebug.mode=debug -dxdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal -dxdebug.client_port=9003 -dzend_extension=xdebug.so -dxdebug.start_with_request=yes index.php` it just doesn't work, it never says it connected. Any idea what's going on?

I already checked things like `php -m`, it says Xdebug is there.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add XDEBUG_MODE="debug" environment variable, from docs:

```
string xdebug.mode = develop #
This setting controls which Xdebug features are enabled.

This setting can only be set in php.ini or files like 99-xdebug.ini that are read when a PHP process starts (directly, or through php-fpm), but not in .htaccess and .user.ini files, which are read per-request.
```

Source - https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode

Comment: This should not be needed if you already have `xdebug.mode=debug`, as you have in your original example `php8 -dxdebug.mode=debug ...`. If you really want to find out what's going on, make a log file (`-dxdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log`) and see what it says, if anything.

Comment: Well what is weird there was nothing in the logs. Actually yea, someone added xdebug.mode=coverage in our images - but it was working previously. Most likely the default mode is debug.